# Cannot Debug In Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors

I have just a form in my VB.Net project and even when I try debugging that - there is nothing going on besides the form being loaded - I get the error:

> No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed.

I've tried using [this solution from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540536/why-cant-i-debug), but this is either oudated or pertains only to C++. I've also tried using [this article from the MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/fdc55319-3f98-4934-b6bd-419cc99fe467), however, this also did not seem to help as I wasn't quite sure what the answer was telling me to do.

Has anybody else came across this problem and found a solution? It's very frustrating that I'm receiving this error and I only have a form showing up.

**Edit:** I found another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970415/no-symbols-are-loaded-in-new-application-framework-vb-net-project) but I don't quite know what that means ... yet. I was going to look into this but I'd really like to know why this doesn't work when Application Framework is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick workaround is to just uncheck "Enable unmanaged code debugging" and "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" in the Debug section of the Project Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running in debug and not release. `Build>Configuration Manager>Active Solution Configuration = Debug`

Comment: The configuration is set to Debug.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all compiler warnings/errors and rebuild. Look at your Sub New() and form_load events closely. Dodgy form inheritance can cause this. Dodgy module level vars also. From memory even when you fix the problem you need to rebuild to get the designer back. Might be a my.Settings issue.

Sorry for imprecise advice, I have had this problem before but I cannot remember the details.

Comment: There is no Sub New() since I have the "application framework" option enabled. This essentially hides all the necessary startup procedures - including the Sub Main() and EnableVisualStyles() - and they cannot be seen by the user. As for the Form_Load event, I only have a message box that should display. As for the references, it is the most basic Windows Forms Application. Any references would be the defaults set by Visual Studio.